# Syntax and Variables in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I'm having some trouble with writing some syntax. I want to echo this

```
'location_1' => $location_1,
```

However, it is not as simple as it seems. When I write the echo statement the integer 1 must be the variable $z. Here is the code I attempted to write

```
echo "'location_' . $z . '' =>' . ${'location_' . $z} . ','";
```

This is what it outputted

```
'location_' . 1 . '' =>' . something . ','
```

$location_1 is equal to the string something. I'm lost at how to do this the right way. Any guides on describing how this syntax works would be a major help too so I can understand it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write variables directly into double quoted strings see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

```
echo "'location_$z' => \$location_$z,";
```

You might want to also read the rest of the [strings doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
echo "'location_$z' => \$location_$z,";
```

You need to escape the $ symbol.  The double quotes represent the thing to echo in this case, whereas the single quotes actually get echoed.

Answer (score 1):

One way is: `echo "'location_{$z}' => \$location_{$z},";`

Edit: Is this what you meant?

```
<?php
$z = 1;
$location_1 = 'something';
echo "'location_$z' => " . ${'location_'. $z} . ',';
```

which produces: `'location_1' => something,`

Why don't you store these variables inside an array for easier access. Something like:

```
$locations = array('location_id' => 'location_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the link to the [echo documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (see the examples, I think they described well how it works)

Answer (score 1):

You can break it into two lines and get the expected output.

For example:

```
$var_location = "$". "location". $z;

echo "'location_" . $z . "' =>'" . $var_location . "','";
```